# Binary read loop continues after the last entry

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, binary

I'm trying reading from a binary file with a while loop with the code below but for some reason the loop doesn't break after the last entry. There are 4 entries, each in a line, with each line in below format.

> StudentID StudentName StudentSurname StudentEmail StudentYear GPA

## **Function to create a filter file.**

```
public bool createGPAFilterFile(string fileName, string GPAFilterFileName, double lowerGPA, double upperGPA){            
        try
        {   
            MainClass sideObj = new MainClass();
            sideObj.createBinaryFile(GPAFilterFileName);
            FileStream stream = File.Open(fileName, FileMode.Open);
            BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

            while (stream.CanRead)
            {
                double readGPA = reader.ReadDouble();

                if (readGPA > lowerGPA && readGPA < upperGPA)
                {
                    UInt32 readStudentID = reader.ReadUInt32();
                    String readStudentName = reader.ReadString();
                    String readStudentSurname = reader.ReadString();
                    String readStudentEmail = reader.ReadString();
                    Byte readStudentYear = reader.ReadByte();
                    sideObj.appendToFile(GPAFilterFileName, readStudentID, readStudentName, readStudentSurname, readStudentEmail, readStudentYear, readGPA);
                }

            }
            reader.Close();
            reader.Dispose();
            stream.Close();
            stream.Dispose();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.Source);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

## **Function that I used in the first place to append the data.**

```
public bool appendToFile (string fileName, UInt32 studentID, string name, string surname, string email, byte classYear, double gpa){ 
        if (!File.Exists (fileName)) {
            bool success = createBinaryFile (fileName);
            if (!success) {

                return false;
            }
        }
        try{
            BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter (File.Open (fileName, FileMode.Append));
            writer.Write (studentID);
            writer.Write (name);
            writer.Write (surname);
            writer.Write (email);
            writer.Write (classYear);
            writer.Write (gpa);
            writer.Close ();
            writer.Dispose ();
            return true;
        }
        catch{
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: `BinaryReader.ReadDouble` does not read a line, it reads 8-bytes from a stream and interprets them as a double precision floating point value - it sounds like you have  a *text* file, and you should be using a `StreamReader`, from your description.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, data is written to a .dat file with BinaryWriter. That was the reason I had to use BinaryReader in the first place. I'm editing the question with the function I used to append data to the .dat file.

Comment: Read the documentation. `CanRead` doesn't do what you think it does :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Thank you @luaan. I tried with checking `while(reader.PeekChar() != -1)` but it throws a `The output char buffer is too small to contain the decoded characters, encoding 'Unicode (UTF-8)' fallback ` error. Would you suggest comparing length and position?

Comment: **Yep, `stream.Position != stream.Length` solved it**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Found a solution for anyone else interested :)

Rather than using, `while(stream.CanRead)` I tried with `while(stream.Position != stream.Length)` and now the code is working as it should.